# The $-u$ argument in obtaining the minimum principle for $\Delta u=0$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm confused by how Evans recovers the **minimum** principle for $\Delta u=0$. Let me first introduce the text, through which $U$ is an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> **THEOREM 4** (Strong maximum principle). *Suppose $u\in C^2(U)\cap C(\bar{U})$ is harmonic within $U$.*
>
> (i) *Then $$\max_{\bar{U}}u=\max_{\partial U}u.$$*
>
> (ii) *Furthermore, if $U$ is connected and there exists a point $x_0\in U$ such that $$u(x_0)=\max_{\bar{U}}u,$$ then $u$ is constant within $U$.*
>
> Assertion (i) is the maximum principle for Laplace's equation, and (ii) is the strong maximum principle. **Replacing $u$ by $-u$, we recover also similar assertions with "min" replacing "max".**

I don't understand why Evans is using the $-u$ argument to get the minimum principle. Okay, I know the negative of the maximum of $u$ is the minimum of $-u$, but what's that for? If one understands how to prove the maximum principle, he/she will be sure to prove the minimum principle without any trouble. I don't see the necessity of the $-u$ argument; even worse, I don't see the usage of the argument. Could somebody give me a hand? Thank you.

Comment: Replacing $u$ by $-u$ in the max principle gives  the same statements immediately with  max changed to min.  It is diffcult to see where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Thank you. The truth is, I don't know why we have to consider $$\max_{\bar{U}}-u=\max_{\partial U}-u.$$ Why not use the same way of proving the maximum principle to prove the minimum principle?

Comment: Will $$\max_{\bar{U}}-u=\max_{\partial U}-u$$ become $$\min_{\bar{U}}u=\min_{\partial U}u?$$ Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer. Indeed, we could prove the minimum principle by using the recipe for the maximum principle. There's nothing wrong with it. However, the same result can be obtained immediately after we observe that, for example,
$$\max_{\bar{U}}-u=-\min_{\bar{U}}u.$$
Note that $-u$ satisfies all the premises of the maximum principle. The minus sign is no bother to us because it will cancel out once we take care of the other term in the equation.